# Javascript - array.map returns several arrays, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js

I am currently trying to parse a CSV file.

The format of the csv file:(only example, because I cannot show the data)

[image]

I used the script d3 for it.

My code currently looks like this: (It reads the csv data and arranges it to my needs.)

```
var myArray = []

d3.csv("Data.csv", function(data){
    myArray.push(data)
    const uniqueKeys = [...new Set(...myArray.map(i => Object.keys(i)))];

const res = uniqueKeys.map(k => {
    return [k, ...myArray.map(i => i[k]).filter(i => i !== null && i !== undefined)];
});
console.log(res);
```

I need an array like:

```
[[Header1,A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1],[Header2,A2,B2,C2,D2,E2],[Header3,A3,B3,C3,D3,E3]...]
```

Now i got the array I need but the problem is, somehow the script outputs several arrays:

[image]

I only need the **last one, since this one is complete.** The other arrays are not complete for some reason. (You can see there are less elements in it???)

I need to:

1. delete all other arrays but not the last one

OR

2. edit the code that it only outputs the complete(last one)

Thank you! :)

Comment: What's the D3 version?

Answer (score 0):

Just get the last one with `pop` calls:

```
const res = uniqueKeys.map(k => {
    return [k, ...myArray.map(i => i[k]).filter(i => i !== null && i !== undefined)];
}).pop().pop();
```

Comment: In the array I have other arrays. And when I do .pop() I get the same amount of arrays but only for the last row......like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5bu8mkxt/1/

Comment: So do you want the last item that my code produces?

Comment: Yes I want the last array I get as ouput

Comment: OK @House97_ - I've edited my answer, does it work for you now?

Comment: No then it only outputs the last element of the first array (the array with the least elements)

Comment: Do you know a better way to import csv data?